# Selenium chromedriver does not close properly

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chromedriver and Java to run automatic web tests. To be able to use extensions in Chrome I'm using my existing browser profile. Since then I'm experiencing following:

1. run a selenium test with green result
2. open Chrome manualy (or run some test)
3. get error message "chrome application did not close properly"[image: error in CZ]

I'm closing browser and the driver with this:

```
@AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() {driver.quit();}
```

I've tried:

```
@AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() {driver.close();}
```

but this closes just browser, not the driver.

After some attempts to fix I simulate pressing CTRL+SHIFT+Q:

```
package SSO_CWP_APPROVAL;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class Keyboard_events {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public Keyboard_events(WebDriver driver) {Keyboard_events.driver = driver;}

    public void ctrl_shift_q() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The sleep is in this case neccessary. Sleeping less time and get the error again.

```
@AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {K_events.ctrl_shift_q();driver.quit();}
```

binaries:

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

chromedriver.exe 2.42

JDK 8u151

Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Is there any better way how to close browser and the driver?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is not reproducible with newest binaries version.

Answer (score 0):

It was propably bug in Google Chrome 69. In version 70 and 71 works `driver.close();driver.quit();` just fine.